# Jmeter, User Defined Variable doesn't recognized when do remote test

Tags: variables, testing, jmeter, distribute

My Jmeter test scripts is very simple like below

```
Thread Group
   - User Defined Variable
       : log_prefix="test"
   - HttpRequest
       : host=www.abc.com, path=/
   - SummaryReport
       : filename = ${log_prefix}_my.log
```

Local test is everything OK, but remote test is a little weird.

I expected to get "test_my.log" file but SummaryReport create "${log_prefix}_my.log" file in the 'bin' directory.

I think User Defined Variable doesn't affects to Listener(Summary Report) when doing remote test. what is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Don't use listeners for anything but tests development and/or debugging. You can get all the necessary information from `.jtl` results file **after** your test is finished, there is no need for having listeners enabled during the test run.

If for some reason you cannot live without this setting you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as a workaround.

- Define `log_prefix` in *user.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) like:

  ```
  log_prefix=test
  ```

  Alternative way of setting it is passing the `log_prefix` property value via [`-G` command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

  ```
  jmeter -Glog_prefix=test -n -t test.jmx -r slave1, slave2 -l result.jtl
  ```
- Change your listener to use the property instead of the variable like:

  ```
  ${__P(log_prefix,)}_my.log
  ```
- That's it, JMeter should replace the function definition with the `log_prefix` property value.

References:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I want to know  Is it normal that 'User defined variable' can not be used during remote testing with 'Listener'? If it's normal, why It's differ from local testing.